# Getting all Buildings in range of 5 miles from specified coordinates

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, presto, amazon-athena

I have database table `Building` with these columns: `name`, `lat`, `lng`

How can I get all `Buildings` in range of 5 miles from specified coordinates, for example these:

-84.38653999999998

33.72024

My try but it does not work:

```
SELECT ST_CONTAINS(
  SELECT ST_BUFFER(ST_Point(-84.38653999999998,33.72024), 5), 
  SELECT ST_POINT(lat,lng) FROM "my_db"."Building" LIMIT 50
);
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/geospatial-functions-list.html

Comment: Do you want answer compatibile with postgis or athena ? Athena is rather very, very simple spatial tool without many usefull functions.

Comment: are you using PostGIS or Athena or PrestoDB?

Comment: AWS Athena database

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Why are you storing *x,y* in separated columns? I strongly suggest you to store them as `geometry` or `geography` to avoid unnecessary casting overhead in query time.

That being said, you can compute and check distances in miles using `ST_DWithin` or `ST_Distance`:

(Test data)

```
CREATE TABLE building (name text, long numeric, lat numeric);
INSERT INTO building VALUES ('Kirk Michael',-4.5896,54.2835);
INSERT INTO building VALUES ('Baldrine',-4.4077,54.2011);
INSERT INTO building VALUES ('Isle of Man Airport',-4.6283,54.0804);
```

[image]

#### ST_DWithin

[`ST_DWithin`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html) returns true if the given geometries are within the specified distance from another. The following query searches for geometries that are in 5 miles radius from `POINT(-4.6314 54.0887)`:

```
SELECT name,long,lat,
  ST_Distance('POINT(-4.6314 54.0887)'::geography,
              ST_MakePoint(long,lat)) * 0.000621371 AS distance
FROM building
WHERE
  ST_DWithin('POINT(-4.6314 54.0887)'::geography,
              ST_MakePoint(long,lat),8046.72); -- 8046.72 metres = 5 miles;

        name         |  long   |   lat   |     distance      
---------------------+---------+---------+-------------------
 Isle of Man Airport | -4.6283 | 54.0804 | 0.587728347062174
(1 row)
```

#### ST_Distance

The function [`ST_Distance`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance.html) (with `geography` type parameters) will return the distance in *meters*. Using this function all you have to do is to convert meters to miles in the end.

**Attention**: Distances in queries using `ST_Distance` are computed in real time and therefore **do not use the spatial index**. So, it is not recommended to use this function in the `WHERE` clause! Use it rather in the `SELECT` clause. Nevertheless the example below shows how it could be done:

```
SELECT name,long,lat,
  ST_Distance('POINT(-4.6314 54.0887)'::geography,
              ST_MakePoint(long,lat)) * 0.000621371 AS distance
FROM building
WHERE 
  ST_Distance('POINT(-4.6314 54.0887)'::geography,
              ST_MakePoint(long,lat)) * 0.000621371 <= 5;

        name         |  long   |   lat   |     distance      
---------------------+---------+---------+-------------------
 Isle of Man Airport | -4.6283 | 54.0804 | 0.587728347062174
(1 row)
```

- Mind the parameters order with [`ST_MakePoint`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakePoint.html): It is longitude,latitude.. **not** the other way around.

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=62bb009a18174d414b7799ddac0e54d9)

Amazon Athena equivalent (distance in degrees):

```
SELECT *, ST_DISTANCE(ST_GEOMETRY_FROM_TEXT('POINT(-84.386330 33.753746)'),
      ST_POINT(long,lat)) AS distance
FROM building
WHERE 
  ST_Distance(ST_GEOMETRY_FROM_TEXT('POINT(-84.386330 33.753746)'),
  ST_POINT(long,lat)) <= 5;
```

Comment: thanks, I just changed a few things since Athena doesn't have for example `ST_MakePoint'` - https://dpaste.de/6o91 but when I run query I can't see any results

Comment: The function `ST_Distance` in PostGIS, when used with `geography` parameters (not `geometry`), it returns the distance in meters, otherwise you might get the values in degrees (depending on the SRS). As I see, the function `ST_GEOMETRY_FROM_TEXT` returns `geometry`, as its name suggests... this might become an issue for this approach.

Comment: meh, that's right, I'll figure out how to solve this

Comment: yep, I got distance as for example `2.082006564070344E-5`

Comment: In this case, if possible, try to work with degrees instead of miles. I honestly never worked with Athena and I'm not sure if the `geography` data type is supported :-(

Comment: Isn't conversion ratio from degree to miles changes with distance to equator?

Comment: Cześć @GrzegorzGrabek yes, for instance: a degree (latitude) at the equator has ~110.5 km, while at the poles ~111.6 km, due to the ellipsoidal shape.

Comment: Hi @JimJones, i thought about longitude degree converting to miles and it changed rather drastically
0° 111.320 km
15° 107.551 km
30° 96.486 km
45° 78.847 km
60° 55.800 km
75° 28.902 km
90° 0.000 km

So constant value of conversion rate can give not correct results when we are not on an equator.

Comment: @GrzegorzGrabek you're totally right. Luckily nobody said otherwise :D

Comment: @JimJones my bad, on first lookI thought that you convert degree to miles not meters to miles *facepalm*. Shame on me :)

Answer (score 6):

First thing first. If possible use Postgis not amazon-athena. Looking on documentation athena looks like the castrated version of a spatial tool.

First - Install postgis.

```
 CREATE EXTENSION postgis SCHEMA public;
```

Now create geometry(if you want to use metric SRID like 3857 for example) or geography (if you want use degree SRID like 4326) column for your data.

```
alter table building add column geog geography;
```

Then transform your point data (lat,long) data to geometry/geography:

```
update building
   set geog=(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lat,long),4326)::geography)
```

Next create spatial index on it

```
create index on buildings using gist(geog);
```

Now you are ready for action

```
select *, 
       st_distance(geog, ST_makePoint(-84.386,33.72024))/1609.34 dist_miles
  from building
 where st_dwithin(geog, ST_makePoint(-84.38653999999998,33.72024),5*1609.34);
```

Few words of explenations:
Index is useful if you have many records in your table.
ST_Dwithin uses index when st_distance doesn't so ST_dwithin will make your query much faster on big data sets.

Answer (score 0):

For aws Athena , try to use this for calculte aprox distance in degrees

```
decimal_degree_distance =   5000.0 * 360.0 / (2.0 * pi() * cos( radians(latitud) ) * 6400000.0)
```

where 5000.0 y distance in meters

is good for near ecuador places