# PostGIS Query always brings back all results

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I'm playing with PostGIS for the first time and I'm getting all the results back regardless of the distance I use on a distance query. My data looks like this:

```
Id                                      GeoLocation
8eb63480-4d63-11ea-b06a-8c1645ef6ad2    POINT (52.6323202 1.2947649)
a0f2dde6-4d64-11ea-b06a-8c1645ef6ad2    POINT (52.6294342 1.2936336)
a0f2dde7-4d64-11ea-b06a-8c1645ef6ad2    POINT (52.6277909 1.2909079)
a0f2dde8-4d64-11ea-b06a-8c1645ef6ad2    POINT (52.6260535 1.2952051)
```

And when I run a query for a point that should be over a mile away:

```
SELECT * FROM "Locations"   WHERE ST_DWithin("GeoLocation", 'POINT(52.6219322 1.2630061)', 1);
```

I get all of the rows back. My understanding is that the distance parameter should be in metres, so I shouldn't get any results back.

Could it be coordinate format issue? What am I missing?

Comment: `dwithin` use the same unit as the geometry CRS, so degrees in your example. All features are within 1 degree of the given coordinate. Cast to geography or use a different projection to use meters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using parameters of type `geography` you get the returned distance in meters, therefore you need to convert it to miles in case you prefer to work with this unit of measurement. If you can cope with degrees, just stick to `geometry`.

```
WITH locations (geolocation) AS (
  VALUES ('POINT (52.6323202 1.2947649)'),
         ('POINT (52.6294342 1.2936336)'),
         ('POINT (52.6277909 1.2909079)'),
         ('POINT (52.6260535 1.2952051)')
) 
SELECT *
FROM locations 
WHERE ST_DWithin(
          geoLocation::geography, 
          'POINT(52.6219322 1.2630061)'::geography, 1609*2.2) ;

         geolocation          
------------------------------
 POINT (52.6294342 1.2936336)
 POINT (52.6277909 1.2909079)
(2 Zeilen)
```

**EDIT**: @JGH pointed out that [`ST_Distance`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance.html) does not use a spatial index and my previous suggestion was to use it instead of [`ST_DWithin`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html). It means I was wrong with my preference for `ST_Distance` :) Here is anyway how to achieve similar results with `ST_Distance` for those still willing to use it:

```
WITH locations (geolocation) AS (
  VALUES ('POINT (52.6323202 1.2947649)'),
         ('POINT (52.6294342 1.2936336)'),
         ('POINT (52.6277909 1.2909079)'),
         ('POINT (52.6260535 1.2952051)')
) 
SELECT *
FROM locations 
WHERE ST_Distance(
          geoLocation::geography, 
          'POINT(52.6219322 1.2630061)'::geography) * 0.000621371 > 2.2 ;

         geolocation          
------------------------------
 POINT (52.6323202 1.2947649)
 POINT (52.6260535 1.2952051)
(2 Zeilen)
```

Further reading: [`Getting all Buildings in range of 5 miles from specified coordinates`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51889638/2275388)

Comment: let's emphasis that `st_distance` does not use a spatial index, while `st_dwithin` does. It is therefore much faster and should be used in `where` clauses.

Comment: @JGH I didn't know that, thanks for pointing out. Just edited my answer accordingly

Comment: Converted to Geography and now SELECT * FROM "Locations"   WHERE ST_DWithin("GeoLocation", 'POINT(52.6219322 1.2630061)'::geography, 3200); works as expected - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since these seem to be coordinates in longitude and latitude, you should use the `geography` data type.