# Find all rows around 10km radius with GORM and PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, go, go-gorm

I would like to list the `races` within a radius of 10km around the `StartAddress` (join table `Address`)

**This is how my models are written:**

```golang
    type (
        // Race model
        Race struct {
            Base // ID, CreatedAt, UpdatedAt, DeletedAt
            Title          string            `json:"title" gorm:"title;"`
            StartAddress   Address           `json:"startaddress" gorm:"foreignKey:StartAddressID"`
            StartAddressID string            `json:"start_address_id" gorm:"type:char(36);start_address_id;"`
            EndAddress     Address           `json:"endaddress" gorm:"foreignKey:EndAddressID"`
            EndAddressID   string            `json:"end_address_id" gorm:"type:char(36);end_address_id;"`
            StartDate      time.Time         `json:"start_date" gorm:"start_date;"`
            EndDate        time.Time         `json:"end_date" gorm:"end_date;"`
        }

        Address struct {
            Base // ID, CreatedAt, UpdatedAt, DeletedAt
            Street  string  `json:"street" gorm:"street;"`
            Zipcode string  `json:"zipcode" gorm:"zipcode;"`
            City    string  `json:"city" gorm:"city;"`
            Lat     float64 `json:"lat" gorm:"lat;"`
            Lng     float64 `json:"lng" gorm:"lng;"`
        }
    )
```

To query my database I use [GORM v2](https://gorm.io/docs/)

I don't know how to write the query that uses the `cube` & `earthdistance` extentions with PostgreSQL through GORM.

I have already added the extensions with :

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION cube;
```

and

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION earthdistance;
```

Like that but with the GORM syntax with the sort by distance :

```sql
SELECT * FROM races
INNER JOIN addresses ON addresses.id = races.start_address_id
AND earth_box(ll_to_earth(48.8589507,2.2770205), 5000) @> ll_to_earth(addresses.lat, addresses.lng)
ORDER BY races.status DESC
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: Hi there. Just out of curiosity, why did you chose earthdistance over postgis for dealing with spatial data? cheers

Comment: @JimJones Thank you for your question, I chose the "earthdistance" car which I found more suitable and it's officially supported by Postgres.
I am open to using PostGIS, or any extension.

Comment: PostGIS is to my knowledge by far the most suitable extension to deal with spatial data. In this answer you can find an example to compute distances: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51889638/2275388

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query that you've got there can be done in Gorm like this:

```golang
var res []Race

db.Model(&Race{}).
    Joins("StartAddress").
    Where("earth_box(ll_to_earth(?,?), ?) @> ll_to_earth(addresses.lat, addresses.lng)", ptLat, ptLng, dist).
    Order("races.status DESC").
    Limit(100).
    Find(&res)
```

To get the order by distance, you'll need to replace the `Order(...).` with:

```golang
    Clauses(clause.OrderBy{
        Expression: clause.Expr{
            SQL: "earth_distance(ll_to_earth(?,?), ll_to_earth(addresses.lat, addresses.lng)) ASC", 
            Vars: []interface{}{ptLat, ptLng}, 
            WithoutParentheses: true,
        },
    }).
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, with both options I have this error: `ERROR:  syntax error at end of input`

`SELECT [...] FROM "races" LEFT JOIN "addresses" "StartAddress" ON "races"."start_address_id" = "StartAddress"."id" WHERE earth_box(ll_to_earth(53.3781516,-9.338521), '5000') @> ll_to_earth(addresses.lat, addresses.lng AND "races"."deleted_at" IS NULL ORDER BY races.status DESC`

Comment: There was a typo in my code, see it? The second ll_to_earth was missing a parens.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I simply had to replace the occurrences "addresses.lat" and "addresses.lng" with "lat" and "lng" if I had an error.