# Query all primary roads from PostGis Database filled with OSM Data within a boundary

Tags: r, postgresql, postgis, openstreetmap, osm2pgsql

I imported OpenStreetMap data through osm2pgsql into PgSQL (PostGIS)
and I would like to get an SF object from the data containing
all primary roads (geometry) within a an area (bbox) into R.

I got lost since I would like to have also relations and nodes
and im not sure if only a query on planet_osm_roads will be sufficient and how the imported data structure is different to osm xml data im normaly working with.
I understand it is probably a bit broader question but

I would appreciate  a start so to say to understand the query language better.

This is my approach but sadly i get an error

```
conn <- RPostgreSQL::dbConnect("PostgreSQL", host = MYHOST,
                               dbname = "osm_data", user = "postgres", password = MYPASSWORD)
pgPostGIS(conn)


a<-pgGetGeom(conn, c("public", "planet_osm_roads"), geom = "way", gid = "osm_id",
          other.cols = FALSE, clauses  = "WHERE highway = 'primary' && ST_MakeEnvelope(11.2364353533134, 47.8050651144447,  11.8882527806375, 48.2423300001326)")
a<-st_as_sf(a)
```

This is an error i get:

```
Error in postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ST_MakeEnvelope"
LINE 2: ...lic"."planet_osm_roads" WHERE "way" IS NOT NULL   ST_MakeEnv...
                                                             ^
)
Error in pgGetGeom(conn, c("public", "planet_osm_roads"), geom = "way",  : 
  No geometries found.
In addition: Warning message:
In postgresqlQuickSQL(conn, statement, ...) :
  Could not create execute: SELECT DISTINCT a.geo AS type 
                        FROM (SELECT ST_GeometryType("way") as geo FROM "public"."planet_osm_roads" WHERE "way" IS NOT NULL   ST_MakeEnvelope(11.2364353533134, 47.8050651144447,  11.8882527806375, 48.2423300001326)) a;
```

This is the db:

```
osm_data=# \d
                  List of relations
  Schema  |        Name        |   Type   |  Owner   
----------+--------------------+----------+----------
 public   | geography_columns  | view     | postgres
 public   | geometry_columns   | view     | postgres
 public   | planet_osm_line    | table    | postgres
 public   | planet_osm_nodes   | table    | postgres
 public   | planet_osm_point   | table    | postgres
 public   | planet_osm_polygon | table    | postgres
 public   | planet_osm_rels    | table    | postgres
 public   | planet_osm_roads   | table    | postgres
 public   | planet_osm_ways    | table    | postgres
 public   | spatial_ref_sys    | table    | postgres
 topology | layer              | table    | postgres
 topology | topology           | table    | postgres
 topology | topology_id_seq    | sequence | postgres




schema_name         table_name geom_column geometry_type     type
1      public    planet_osm_line         way    LINESTRING GEOMETRY
2      public   planet_osm_point         way         POINT GEOMETRY
3      public planet_osm_polygon         way      GEOMETRY GEOMETRY
4      public   planet_osm_roads         way    LINESTRING GEOMETRY




                      Table "public.planet_osm_roads"
       Column       |           Type            | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------------------+---------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 osm_id             | bigint                    |           |          | 
 access             | text                      |           |          | 
 addr:housename     | text                      |           |          | 
 addr:housenumber   | text                      |           |          | 
 addr:interpolation | text                      |           |          | 
 admin_level        | text                      |           |          | 
 aerialway          | text                      |           |          | 
 aeroway            | text                      |           |          | 
 amenity            | text                      |           |          | 
 area               | text                      |           |          | 
 barrier            | text                      |           |          | 
 bicycle            | text                      |           |          | 
 brand              | text                      |           |          | 
 bridge             | text                      |           |          | 
 boundary           | text                      |           |          | 
 building           | text                      |           |          | 
 construction       | text                      |           |          |
```

Comment: The reason of the question is to get a sample out of db.

Comment: @Andreas your `WHERE` clause is missing an `AND` operator: it has to be `WHERE way IS NOT NULL AND ST_MakeEnvelope(...`. That's what postgres is complaining about. See the query generated in the error message  Could you try it?

Comment: @JimJones Thank you but i get an error: Error in postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  argument of AND must be type boolean, not type geometry
LINE 2: ...RE "way" IS NOT NULL  AND highway = 'primary' AND ST_MakeEnv...
                                                             ^

Comment: If i use psql directly this sequence works: "SELECT *
  FROM planet_osm_roads
WHERE ST_Contains(
  ST_Transform(
    ST_MakeEnvelope(11.2364353533134,47.8050651144447,11.8882527806375,48.2423300001326,4326)
    ,3857)
  ,planet_osm_roads.way);"  but if i use it with pgGetGeom it does not

Comment: @Andreas ah .. my bad. I see now that `way` is your geometry column. The query in your last post looks just fine, but somehow the query genenrated in your code looks different. I honestly know nothing about pgGetGeom, but I would try to add the `ST_Contains` function to the code, as you've shown in your last post.

Comment: @JimJones i figured out another way to do it (see my Answer) could you check if my BBOX Area is getting considered? Do you know by chance if ST_MakeEnvelope is the correct way to do it? basically i just want roads within that area.

Comment: @Andreas I never used ST_Envelope for this purpose, since in most of my use cases I just have a coordinate pair and a radius, so I almost always use ST_DWithin and ST_Buffer. However, since you already the area (bbox), there is no need to use it :) you can `explain` your query to see if the indexes are being used ... these operations can get expensive! ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query looks just fine. Check the following example:

```
WITH planet_osm_roads (highway,way) AS (
  VALUES 
    ('primary','SRID=3857;POINT(1283861.57 6113504.88)'::geometry), --inside your bbox
    ('secondary','SRID=3857;POINT(1286919.06 6067184.04)'::geometry)  --somewhere else ..
)
SELECT highway,ST_AsText(way)
FROM planet_osm_roads
WHERE 
   highway IN ('primary','secondary','tertiary') AND
   planet_osm_roads.way && ST_Transform(
  ST_MakeEnvelope(11.2364353533134,47.8050651144447,11.8882527806375,48.2423300001326, 4326),3857
);

 highway |          st_astext           
---------+------------------------------
 primary | POINT(1283861.57 6113504.88)
```

This image illustrates the BBOX and the points used in the example above

- Check the [`documentation`](https://postgis.net/docs/reference.html#operators-bbox) for more information on the bbox intersection operator `&&`.

[image]

However, there are a few things to consider.

- In case you're creating the BBOX yourself in order to have an area for [`ST_Contains`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Contains.html), consider simply using [`ST_DWithin`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html). It will basically do the same, but you only have to provide a reference point and the distance.
- Depending on the distribution of `highway` types in the table `planet_osm_roads` and considering that your queries will **always** look for either `primary`,`secondary` or `tertiary` highways, creating a [`partial index`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-partial.html) could significantly improve performance. As the documentation says:

> A partial index is an index built over a subset of a table; the subset
> is defined by a conditional expression (called the predicate of the
> partial index). The index contains entries only for those table rows
> that satisfy the predicate. Partial indexes are a specialized feature,
> but there are several situations in which they are useful.

So try something like this:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_planet_osm_roads_way ON planet_osm_roads USING gist(way) 
WHERE highway IN ('primary','secondary','tertiary');
```

And also `highway` needs to be indexed. So try this ..

```
CREATE INDEX idx_planet_osm_roads_highway ON planet_osm_roads (highway);
```

.. or even another partial index, in case you can't delete the other data but you don't need it for anything:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_planet_osm_roads_highway ON planet_osm_roads (highway) 
WHERE highway IN ('primary','secondary','tertiary');
```

You can always identify bottlenecks and check if the query planer is using your index with [`EXPLAIN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-explain.html).

Further reading

- [Getting all Buildings in range of 5 miles from specified coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51889638/2275388)
- [Buffers (Circle) in PostGIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49985343/2275388)
- [How can I set data from on table to another according spatial relation geometries in these tables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66688480/2275388)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.
This is how you would get an SF object out of PostGIS Database filled with OSM Data within `11.2364353533134,47.8050651144447,11.8882527806375,48.2423300001326` BBOX:

```
library(sf)
library(RPostgreSQL)
library(tictoc)
pw <- MYPASSWORD
drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
con <- dbConnect(drv, dbname = "osm_data",
                 host = "localhost", port = 5432,
                 user = "postgres", password = pw)


tic()
sf_data = st_read(con, query = "SELECT osm_id,name,highway,way
  FROM planet_osm_roads
WHERE highway = 'primary' OR highway = 'secondary' OR highway = 'tertiary'AND ST_Contains(
  ST_Transform(
    ST_MakeEnvelope(11.2364353533134,47.8050651144447,11.8882527806375,48.2423300001326,4326)
    ,3857)
  ,planet_osm_roads.way);")
toc()

RPostgreSQL::dbDisconnect(con)
```

I have to verify if BBOX values are actually getting considered .. im not sure.

Comment: Bbox isn't taken into acount...