# rgeo point near MULTILINESTRING

Tags: postgresql, postgis, rgeo

Having a geometry column `wkb_geometry`, srid 4326 that is a `MULTILINESTRING` I would like to determine which of these records are within a predetermined distance (say 5000m) of a geometry object `POINT`

while the following method allows to determine if a polygon contains a point

```
def self.containing_latlon(lat,lon, polygon)
  ewkb = EWKB.generate(RGeo::Geographic.simple_mercator_factory.point(lon, lat).projection)
  where("ST_Intersects(polygon, ST_GeomFromEWKB(E'\\\\x#{ewkb}'))")
end
```

`ST_Intersects` is clearly not an option, as it applies to "any portion of space then they intersect".
I have not found documentation in order to determine if a line is within X distance of a point.  But possibly the question is reversed?  Should the question not be is the point within a polygon defined by the MULTILINESTRING and a buffer.

How would the above method need to be modified in order to execute this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`ST_DWithin`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html) instead.

For distances using meters cast the parameters to `geography`, e.g. 5km:

```
SELECT * FROM t
WHERE ST_DWithin('POINT(7.00 51.82)'::geography,geom::geography,5000);
```

If you're happy with the unit of measurement of your SRS, just stick to `geometry

```
SELECT * FROM t
WHERE ST_DWithin('POINT(7.00 51.82)'::geometry,geom,42);
```

The `::` after the WKT literals is a postgres syntax to cast data types. But as it is customary in postgres, there are many ways to do the same thing. The following example casts a WKT literal into a `geometry` using different techniques:

```
SELECT 
  CAST('SRID=4326;POINT(1 2)' AS geometry),
  'SRID=4326;POINT(1 2)'::geometry,
  ST_GeomFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(1 2)'),
  ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(1,2),4326);

-[ RECORD 1 ]---+---------------------------------------------------
geometry        | 0101000020E6100000000000000000F03F0000000000000040
geometry        | 0101000020E6100000000000000000F03F0000000000000040
st_geomfromtext | 0101000020E6100000000000000000F03F0000000000000040
st_setsrid      | 0101000020E6100000000000000000F03F0000000000000040
```

Further reading: [Getting all Buildings in range of 5 miles from specified coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51889638/2275388)

Comment: It is `ST_DWithin` and not `ST_Within`.  I had cast aside the latter given the conditions, but not known of the former... which requires a tad more attention to decipher given the use of caps!  May I also ask about the syntax of the double-colon as I had not come across it yet in postgis.net/docs ?

Comment: @Jerome the `::` is a postgres syntax. It is a short form for `CAST(value AS datatype)`. I will add a few examples in my answer. Did ST_DWithin work in your use case?

Comment: I believe it will (found docs for it - the shoe fits); I am charting out a work plan and this element was the only gaping hole.  I will be trying  shortly as the steps get enacted.

Comment: Yes, that worked. Required some finagling with the attribute syntax:  `where("ST_DWITHIN('#{class.attribute.as_text}'::geography,wkb_geometry::geography,5000)").all`