# Getting all Stores in range of 5 kilometers from specified coordinates in AWS Athena

Tags: sql, geospatial, postgis, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I have database table in Athena named stores with these columns: name, location

How can I get all store names in range of 5 kilometers from specified coordinates, for example these:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps this answer is what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51889638/2275388

Comment: @JimJones These answers aren't working for me in Athena. I think those answer are based on PostGIS, whereas I want to achieve in Athena. Thank you.

Comment: The very last part of my answer addresses Amazon Athena -  at least the OP said it worked at that time. Check it out again https://stackoverflow.com/a/51889638/2275388

Comment: @JimJones, Amazon Athena query you mentioned works perfectly. Need a small help here, The distance is in degree, How do I need to conver it to Kilometers? multiply it by 111? Sorry to comment here as I am unable to comment it in you original answer

Comment: The easiest way would be to cast the `geometry` column to `geography`. Can Amazon Athena handle it? e.g. `SELECT geom_column::geography FROM mytable`

Comment: or in case long/lat are split in numeric columns `SELECT ST_POINT(long,lat)::geography FROM mytable`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few years back I created a radial search (as the crow flys) of all businesses X miles from a specific location. I give the longitude and latitude of my current position, and the radius size I want to use.
It uses a prepared SQL statement - you should be able to modify it for your own purposes. It used PHP but should be simple to amend.

For my project, longitude (_lng) and latitude (_lat) were in separate columns.

The following SQL creates a "_distance" column from a radius calculation and then orders it by distance ascending.

```
$sql = "SELECT a.id,  a._name, a._address, a._lat, a._lng, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(%f ) ) * cos( radians( a._lat ) ) * cos( radians( a._lng ) - radians(%f ) ) + sin( radians(%f) ) * sin( radians( a._lat ) ) ) ) AS _distance FROM {$tablename} a  HAVING _distance < %d ORDER BY _distance ASC";
$res = $conn->get_results($conn->prepare($sql, [$current_lat_pos,$current_long_pos,$current_lat_pos,$provided_radius] ));
```

Comment: Yes James, This formula works for me Thank you very much. I am also looking at how to achieve this using Athena inbuilt functions, I have tried a couple of things but doesn't work.

Comment: Sadly I can't help you on that, but glad that the sql works for you

Comment: Is that formula used in your query is called as Haversine formula?

Answer (score 3):

Athena is using [Presto](https://prestodb.io/) internally which in turn supports [geospatial functions](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/geospatial.html#functions-geospatial--page-root) including `ST_Distance`:

> `ST_Distance(Geometry, Geometry)` -> `double`
> Returns the 2-dimensional cartesian minimum distance (based on spatial ref) between two geometries in projected units.

> `ST_Distance(SphericalGeography, SphericalGeography)` -> `double`
> Returns the great-circle distance in meters between two `SphericalGeography` points.

And `ST_Point` to create a point

> `ST_Point(x, y)` → `Point`
> Returns a geometry type point object with the given coordinate values.

> Use `to_spherical_geography()` function to convert a geometry object to geography object. For example, `ST_Distance(ST_Point(-71.0882, 42.3607), ST_Point(-74.1197, 40.6976))` returns 3.4577 in the unit of the passed-in values on the euclidean plane, while `ST_Distance(to_spherical_geography(ST_Point(-71.0882, 42.3607)), to_spherical_geography(ST_Point(-74.1197, 40.6976)))` returns 312822.179 in meters.

```sql
select ST_Distance(ST_Point(-71.0882, 42.3607), ST_Point(-74.1197, 40.6976)), 
    ST_Distance(to_spherical_geography(ST_Point(-71.0882, 42.3607)), to_spherical_geography(ST_Point(-74.1197, 40.6976)))
```

Output:

| _col0 | _col1 |
| --- | --- |
| 3.457729581676387 | 312822.1793690028 |